# Failed - Registering simulator runtime with CoreSimulator failed - While downloading simulator for Vision OS

Tags: swift, swiftui, visionos

I've been downloading VisionOS simulator, but it shows me this error when I reach about downloading. I have tried 5-6 times, but the same error occurs each time, and it requires starting the download from the beginning.

[image]

I'm using macOS Sonoma 14.2.1 (23C71) and Xcode 15.2.

Thanks in advance for helping me....

Comment: I do have Sonoma **14.3.1**, Xcode 15.2  - and visionOS 1.0 simulator installed. So, no problem.  Does the Info button in your error message reveal more information?